# Express API confusion - what exact part of my express app is the API?

Tags: javascript, express

I feel kinda dumb for asking this, but I'm building an express API app on a Codecademy exercise and I don't actually understand which part of the app is the API.

Basically, you have a file containing a bunch of quotes which are displayed to the browser. Via the browser, you can pull a random quote (upon clicking a 'random quote button'), pull all the quotes, or add your own quote.

So where in all of this is the API? I understand that an API is an interface between two pieces of software, but I don't get how it works in this context. Anyway, just as an example, here's the code for the 'fetch all quotes' functionality:

scripts.js

```
fetchAllButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('/api/quotes')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      renderError(response);
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    renderQuotes(response.quotes);
  });
});
```

server.js

```
app.get('/api/quotes', (req, res) => {
  let quoteMatch;
  let quoteSearch = req.query.person;
  if (quoteSearch == undefined) {  
    res.send({quotes: quotes})
  } else {
    quotesMatch = quotes.filter(quote => {
      return quote.person == quoteSearch && quote;
    });
    if (quoteMatch) {
      res.send({ quotes: quotesMatch });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Author not found!! ');
    }
  }
})
```

data.js

```
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: 'We build our computer (systems) the way we build our cities: over time, without a plan, on top of ruins.',
    person: 'Ellen Ullman'
  },
  {
    quote: 'The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit.',
    person: 'Anonymous'
  },
```

Comment: which codecademy course is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API code in `server.js` file.

`scripts.js`: calling API from Front-end side.

Answer (score 1):

Your script.js is client from where you are hitting the request to  /api/quotes and your server.js is API which is handling the request

```
app.get('/api/quotes', (req, res) => {
})
```

this piece of code in server.js file is called route in API which basically determine to handle the request if any request is coming on this url '/api/quotes'

Answer (score 1):

Your API is server.js listening by url: '/api/quotes' then response res.send({quotes: quotes} by html get method.